# Customize commit message when editing an Azure DevOps's wiki page

Tags: azure-devops

By default the commit message is "Updated [Article Name]" which i do not like very much. At least, I want to be able to add a custom prefix. Is anyone aware of a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save with a custom revision message, select the context menu icon next to Save.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But i also wonder if there is a way to make that prefix added automatically, so i do not have to type it every time.

Comment: At present, it cannot be automated. You can submit this feature request on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to make adding a revision message compulsory in Azure devops ?